# How to remove extra <p> in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and currently developing a theme on it. I have noticed that Wordpress adds `<p>` tags all over the page. Do you know any plugin or a workaround to avoid this?

Comment: would it not be easier to fix the spacing in the css for p tags within the loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this to your **functions.php**, this should give the result you're looking for:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: I have added the above line in theme's function.php but still its adding an <p> in front of <script> tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming you have the html code in variable `$html_code`

```
$html_code = preg_replace('/<\/?p>/','', $html_code);
```

Comment: That'll remove ALL `<p>` tags, not just the ones from WordPress.

Comment: Yes, i'm assuming that this comes from some wysiwyg editor in Wordpress, so we're actually removing all of those <p>s.

Answer (score 0):

The [WP Unformatted](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-unformatted/) module will remove that default filter.

Comment: here is a newer version that is compatible up to 2.9.2 http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-wordpress-autop-filter/