# Wordpress breacks pure CSS hover slider

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a CSS mouseover slider fully functional here http://jsfiddle.net/gU4sw/13/ .

When I add this code do wordpress [page](http://fanfan-shop.ru/test/), it doesn't work... :(

Can anyone take a look and suggest a quick fix please ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i saw your code there is an unclosed `<p>` which is look like this `<p></a>`. In your WP code it's look like this:

```
<div id="id1" class="item">
 <a href="#"><br />
  <h1 class="slh1">Air Duct Cleaning</h1>
  <p>Mauris nec convallis erat. Nunc scelerisque dui non sem aliquam feugiat. Ut placerat mollis mauris, vel porttitor lectus semper vel. Nam sit.<br /><u><span style="color:blue;">learn more</span></u></p>
  <p>
 </a>
</div>
```

So, remove that unnecessary `P`.

Comment: man i get it, wordpress add those <p> automatically, i wraped my code in <code></code> tags and it rendered ok. still looks messy, but at least its working now :) thank you!

Comment: hmm, for some reason it doesn't work on other WP installation, coul'd you plz take a look here http://bit.ly/GJQycs , I don't see any <p> this time

Comment: You have to check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086016/how-to-remove-extra-p-in-wordpress may be that's help you

Comment: ok , I removed the filter, however I think now its something else thats causing page to break here bit.ly/GJQycs :(